# Return an array of values from toggled images in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, toggle

I am using a jquery post to return an xml dataset.  I was originally using drop down form controls to filter the data as it was returned.

Now I want to be able to display a list of manufacturer icons and then have the user click on those to toggle them on and off.

```
$('#sho').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('highlight');
    if ($(this).hasClass('highlight')){
            $(this).attr('alt','sho');
            alert(manufac);
    } else {
            $(this).attr('alt','');
    }});
```

Currently I have the toggle code in place so that the image just gets a box around it when it is clicked.  I am also setting the ALT attribute with a value.  I want to be able to gather all the alt attribute that have values and pass them to my jquery post.

```
function loadXML(so) {
<!-- Clothing Version -->
timestamp = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000);

$("#wrapper").html('<div id="load"><img src="http://static.phmotorcyclescom.dev/images/loading.gif" alt="loading" align="center"  /></div>');
$("#results").empty();
$.post("http://www.phmotorcycles.current/supportScripts/clothingXML.asp",{  
    productGroup: "hel",  
    sortOrder: so,
    qt: "group",
    ts: timestamp,
    manufacturer:$("input:checkbox[name='man[]']:checked").map(function() {
        return $(this).val();
    }).get()}, <----- I need to replace this section of code
    function(xml) {
        convertXML(xml);
        $("#wrapper").empty();
        $('#results').html("Your Product was not found");
    },"xml")
```

}

Ultimately the value that gets passed to the manufactuer variable is simply a comma separated list of values such as ara,sho,sha,ara

Does anybody have any thoughts on this please.  I have tried using the .each() method and have managed to get it to alert all the positive values but I cannot concatenate them into a string.

```
$('img').each(function(){
            var id = $(this).attr("id");
            var altVal = $(this).attr("alt");
            if (altVal != '') {
                alert($('img#' + id).attr('alt'));
            }
        });
```

As always help is much appreciated.

Cheers
Graham

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this..

```
manufacturer : function() {
    var ar= new Array();
     $("img.highlight").each(function(){
     ar.push($(this).attr("alt"));
    });
   return ar.join(",");
}
```

jsFiddle to show uses of push and and join

http://jsfiddle.net/jCdpf/